# Using content editable to submit changes with ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page that dynamically produces multiple lines which contain a `<p contenteditable="true">`. I want to submit the changes to that field on the `blur` event. I am using the HTML `data` attribute to assign a number to each field which makes it unique.

Here is the code that I have so you can see what I mean.

PHP - This dynamically produces the fields

```
 $row = ''; 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo '<tr><td class="columnButton vertAlign"><button data-complete="'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm completeTask" action="completeTask" method="POST">Complete</button></td><td class="vertAlign"><div class="task"><p class="taskText" data-task="'.$row['id'].'" contenteditable="true">'.$row['list'].'</p></div></td><td class="vertAlign columnButton"><button method="POST" action="delete" type="submit" class="deleteTask btn-sm btn btn-danger pull-right" data-id="'.$row['id'].'">Delete</button></td></tr>';
    }
```

jQuery - This will handle the AJAX POST

```
var dataTask = $(this).attr('data-task');
    $('.taskText').on('blur', function(){
        alert(dataTask);
    });
```

I am trying to use the `alert` to show that the `blur` event is working, but it is not. If I can get this alert to work with each `contenteditable` field, I can get my AJAX to work. How can I assign this event to each `contenteditable` field and make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are creating `<p>` tag with class `taskText` class from jquery itself(dynamically created html),that is why you have to bind event `blur` as shown below :

Try this :

```
$(document).on('blur','.taskText',function(){
   var dataTask = $(this).attr('data-task');
   alert(dataTask);
});
```

OR

```
$('body').on('blur','.taskText',function(){
   var dataTask = $(this).attr('data-task');
   alert(dataTask);
});
```

See More here :- http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: That works perfectly! What makes using `$(document)` work and not my solution, if you do not mind elaborating?

Comment: It makes me wait 12 minuted before I can mark it as the answer. Not sure why, but I always have to come back to mark an answer on here. Thank you for your help!